# Search conditions returning no results / breaking

Tags: attributes, magento2.4, eav-attributes

I have a couple custom modules, one for adding eav attributes to customers, and I had a module that filtered those customers based on the attribute values, which 'was' working.

When I say "filter" I mean the same type of conditions block as is used in cart price rules.

Another module creates labels over product images, based on arbitrary eav attributes. I have a custom attribute that shows "Compare At Price" for what other retailers sell the same product for. The label was filtered on a condition of "compare_at_price is greater than 0" and again, it 'was' working.

For some reason, these two filters have stopped returning results, and I am at a loss for where to look. Anyone else have any experience with eav attributes and filters and know what could be wrong?